# Nullable reference type and implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

When using "Implement interface" quick action for [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface I am getting

```
class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

The nullable reference type is expected, this force me to use `?.Invoke()` rather than getting `NullReferenceException`.

However for [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter) it's:

```
class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I expect instead to see `object?` everywhere for method arguments and return types. Why is it not?

Should I manually do this change?

---

Another thing I noticed:

```
interface IA
{
    object? Test(object? arg);
}

class A : IA
{
    public object? Test(object? arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

interface IB
{
    object Test(object arg);
}

class B : IB
{
    public object Test(object arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Means the "Implement interface" quick action simply follows the method signatures from interface definition. Does this means that the signature of all standard library interfaces needs to be updated?

I am using VS2022 preview 4 and .Net 6.0 btw.

Comment: Notice that adding nullable context support takes a lot of time, I wouldn't expect MS to rewrite an enormous part of the .NET so quickly. AFAIK, they are adding support gradually

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, means it was added for `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but not for `IValueConverter` yet? Will come later, hopefully at release of .Net 6.0?

Comment: No clue at all, maybe they'll add it for .NET 6, maybe not. Easiest would be to post a thread on the .NET GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this means that the signature of all standard library interfaces needs to be updated?

Yes, it does.

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

> The .NET runtime APIs have all been annotated [for null-state static analysis] in .NET 5. You improve the static analysis by annotating your APIs to provide semantic information about the null-state of arguments and return values.

This is why you're seeing `PropertyChangedEventHandler?` for `INotifyPropertyChanged`; it's been updated to include said annotations.

However, the most recent version of the `IValueConverterInterface` is [Windows Desktop 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0). From that page, you can see that it has not yet been updated to take advantage of nullable reference types.

Comment: Another piece of evidence that IValueConverter has not been updated yet: The return type of `Convert` is `object`, but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) explicitly mentions `null` as a valid return value.

Comment: The quote refer to attributes, like [NotNullWhenAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute). But I agree I shell just wait for .Net next release and in a meantime simply update implementations manually, right?

Comment: @Sinatr That sounds reasonable IMO.